# “This profile is locked” message on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I’m not on Facebook. Recently, when I was looking for one of my friend’s Facebook profile, it displayed a message under her profile picture saying

> this profile is locked

Is this a new Facebook feature? Or is it something else?

Comment: If you are not on Facebook how you were looking for friend's profile? Can you add screenshot of that message?

Comment: @serenesat I googled her name and selected the search result from Facebook. The message just said “This profile is locked” just under her profile picture.

Comment: I just checked to get a screenshot and I don’t see the message anymore.

Comment: I have written answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's for a transient issue that has since been resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is it was an accident that made it to production, probably, as it's now gone[image: Here is a screenshot].

I only saw it on mobile facebook in the browser from about 1am-4am last night. I no longer see the message "This profile is locked." When I attempted clicking on the badges.

The blue "pill" button linked to https://m.facebook.com/private_sharing/home_view/?entry_point=profile_blue_pill but 404ed.

I saw it on everyone's profiles including my own, however was unable to click or load any of these.

Answer (score 1):

"This profile is locked" means it is talking about profile picture. If an user has locked their profile picture (set it as private), when someone clicked or hover over mouse on profile picture it show that this profile is locked. In a locked profile you cannot see the full version of that picture. Only display will be visible. This is not related to account lock.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. It’s a new feature right? I haven’t seen it before.

Comment: Can't say. I am not sure.

Comment: Not accurate, as it seems to apply to all pictures, it's just that the profile and cover photos are public; but yeah, it mostly "protects" the profile picture as it must be public. It says "John Doe's profile is locked. Only their friends can see their photos". It is also said that this feature is available only in certain countries.